# Can't run app on old API level in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

My app developed using API 19, but I include support library v4 and trying run it in emulator under API 8 (using eclipse). So my app crashes with error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo / java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` of my ActivityMain.

I have also included in my project several libs such as jsoup and GA.

Any suggestions? Thanx

Comment: paste code ComponentInfo activity please

Comment: @KostyaKhuta `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.interfax.west/com.interfax.west.ActivityMain}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.interfax.west.ActivityMain in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.interfax.west-2.apk]`

Comment: no, i want to saw activity code, not exception

Comment: @KostyaKhuta `public class ActivityMain extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener`

Comment: In Api LEvel 8 there is no ActionBar.TabListener

Comment: The whole `MainActivity` Code and complete error log from logcat please.

Comment: So what full code gives you?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should extend [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) if you want to support the actionbar for < API 11

```
public class ActivityMain extends ActionBarActivity
```

Instead of:

```
public class ActivityMain extends FragmentActivity
```

Comment: So I figure out that my app should work correctly in API 11, right?

Comment: ActionBar APIs were first added in API 11, so in API 11 your current code should work. If you want to support actionbar in lower APIs you will need to use android.support.v7 lib (ActionBarActivity is in that lib, too), see also the guide here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html